# How do you setup Mvvmcross SQLite plugin to be tested?

Tags: sqlite, nunit, mvvmcross

I'm quite new to mvvmcross and I'm working on an app that uses SQLite plugin as "backend" for the model. (WinRT and WP/8 only at the moment but porting it to Droid and IOS when firts two platforms work ok).
I would like to setup some tests using NUnit and VS2012 but having some difficulties to find examples on how to initialize the framework and the plugin in the SetupFixture class/setup for the test.
Can someone who already have done this point me in the right direction ?

Thank you very much for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

I generally don't test at the SQLite interface level itself.

Instead, I generally wrap the use of SQLite inside very simple repositories. Each of these repositories provides an interface. Each of the repositories and SQLite itself is assumed to be a known good components - so it not tested. And this allows me to then test other code using Mocks for these repositories, rather than trying to mock or use SQLite itself.

---

If you want to test at the SQLite level:

- You could write a ISQLiteConnection test implementation
- Or you could write something that used one of the SQLite on Windows plugins for testing